# object oriented form validation

Tags: javascript

I created this form validation script, where a "valid" object holds properties with boolean values. First, the code loops through every required element in the form and performs two types of generic checks.
1. Does the element have the required attribute?
If so, does it have a value?
2. Does the value match with the type attribute?
E.g., Does an email input hold an email address?
Once the generic checks have been performed, the script then makes some checks that apply to individual elements on the form.

TRACKING VALID ELEMENTS
To keep track of errors, an object called va1id is created.As the code loops through each element performing the generic checks, a property is added to the va1id object for each element:
• The property name is the value of its id attribute.
• The value is a Boolean. Whenever an error is found on an element, this value is set to fa1se.

The problem i encounter is an error that says "TypeError: validateType is undefined".
what do i do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>

                <form action="new_facebook.html" method="get" class="form2" novalidate>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your first name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder= "first name"  class="sign_up all names" id = "first_name" required/>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your surname</span>
                    <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname"  class="sign_up all names" id = "surname" required/><br/>


                    <span id = "emailError" class = "hidden">email address</span>
                    <input type="email" name="mobile_number_or_email_address" placeholder="email address"  class="sign_up2 all" id= "mobile_number_or_email_address" class = "hidden" required /><br/>

                    <span id = "passwordError" class = "hidden">password</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="new password"  class="sign_up2 all" id = "password" required />
                    <br/><br/>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" id="submit"/>

                </form>

        <script src = "jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.form2').on('submit' , function(e){

                    var valid = {};
                    var isValid;
                    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('all');

                    for(var i = 0; i<elements.length ; i++){
                        isValid = validateRequired(elements[i]) && validateTypes(elements[i]);
                        valid[elements[i].id] = isValid;

                        if(!isValid){
                            elements[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
                        }else{
                            elements[i].style.border = '';
                        }
                    }

                    function validateRequired(el){
                            if(el.required){  // if the element is required
                                return el.value;
                            }else{ // if the element is not required
                                return true;
                            }
                    }

                    function validateTypes(el){
                        var type = el.getAttribute('type');

                        if(validateType[type] === 'function'){
                            return validateType[type](el);
                        }else{ // no need to validate 
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    var validateType = {
                        email: function(el){
                            var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                            return emailPattern.test(el.value);
                        }
                    }

                    for(var property in valid){

                        if(!valid[property]){
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }

                    //console.log(typeof validateType);

                });

            }); // end of document ready
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails at:

```
 validateType[type] === "function"
```

inside `validateTypes` which you call inside the `for` loop, however you declare `validateType` after the loop, so it doesn't exist at the time the loop runs. If you declare `validateType` before the loop, the error should disappear.

Comment: it worked; so i should not call an object's method before declaration of the object.